# Recursive Python Function - Can't seem to store values

Tags: python, recursion

I'm using a recursive function to return the optimal path between two points, based on the Floyd Warshall algorithm.

I'm getting the path, but for some reason it's only returning one stop, not all stops along the path.

I'm sure the answer is right in front of me, but I've been staring at this code for some time and can't seem to get it right.

```
def pathsense(nextstop, i, j):

    if nextstop[i][j] == i:
        miolopath[i][j] = miolopath[i][j] + ' ' + str(nextstop[i][j])
        return
    else:
        miolopath[i][j] = miolopath[i][j] + ' ' + str(nextstop[i][j])
    pathsense(nextstop, i, nextstop[i][j])


# chamar comando para construir etapas

def pathreconstruction(nextstop, nV):
    for i in range(nV):
        for j in range(nV):
            miolopath[i][j] = i
            if i != j and distance[i][j] != 999999:
                pathsense(nextstop, i, j)
                optimalpath[i][j] = miolopath[i][j] + ' ' + str(j)
```

The pathreconstruction part calls back the pathsense (recursive) function. I need it to record all `nextstops[i][j]` until it reaches the last one on the path.

For some reason it's only returning one of the stops along the path.

Any help?

Cheers

Comment: Where are `distance` and `optimalpath`?

Comment: I'm not sure of the intended logic, but your function as it stands always `return`s something straight away, in both the `if` and `else` clause. The recursive call is never reached because it's after a `return` statement.

Comment: A recursive function must *build* a return value from the value returned by the recursion plus its own contribution.

Comment: You have `return nextstop[i][j]` before the recursive call. That will return immediately.

Comment: Switched it up. 

Got it. But if I would like to store every ```` nextstop[i][j] ``` inside the "else" condition. Does the ```return nextstop[i][j]``` store that or will it only store the last one?

Answer (score 0):

```
def pathsense(nextstop, i, j):

    if nextstop[i][j] == i:
        return
    else:
        return nextstop[i][j]
        pathsense(nextstop, i, nextstop[i][j])
```

`pathsense` wouldn't be called again, since the function already exits by returning a value. Rearrange the statements to solve this.

```
def pathsense(nextstop, i, j):

    if nextstop[i][j] == i:
        return
    else:
        pathsense(nextstop, i, nextstop[i][j])
        return nextstop[i][j]
```

Comment: Got it. But if I would like to store every ```` nextstop[i][j] ``` inside the "else" condition. Does the ```return nextstop[i][j]``` store that or will it only store the last one?

Comment: Where are you storing anything inside the function? I don't see any assignment

Comment: I've added an assignment now, but for some reasons it's returning 0.0 (or None), still debugging.

Comment: Edited! Let me know if this should help. It still seems to be returning the last step in the iteration....

Comment: I think the problem lies in your ```nextstop``` matrix probably